# Change color of inactive IconButton

Tags: flutter

I have following widgets implemented:
[image]

Which parameter of ThemeData I should change to change grey color of IconButton?

Widget code:

```
TextFormField(
                    controller: _loginPageViewModel.emailTEC,
                    validator: _loginPageViewModel.validator.validateEmail,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: S.of(context).email,
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: _loginPageViewModel.emailTEC.clear,
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    )
                )
```

ThemeData code:

```
ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      //primaryColor: const Color(0xFFF8C537),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFDDA1),
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
        color: Color(0xFFE53935),
      ),
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: const Color(0xFFFFD151),
            onPrimary: Colors.black,
            elevation: 0.5
        ),
      ),
      inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFFFD151)),
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFEDB230))
        ),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFFFD151)),
        ),
      ),
colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(primary: Color(0xFFEDB230)),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.android),
            color: condition ? Colors.white : Colors.grey,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
```

Also here is a property:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/disabledColor.html

```
IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  iconSize: 50,
                  splashRadius: 40,
                  disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: null,
                )
```

Comment: Thanks for help :) I would prefer to keep color definitions inside ThemeData if possible.
I tried using disabledColor in ThemeData, but it doesn't have any effect

Comment: If you will show some code we can find out why not working or what you have tried.

Comment: You are right, I included code in the problem description

Answer (score 0):

While the `IconButton` is being used as `suffixIcon`, you can change its color from `InputDecoration`.

```dart
theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
  inputDecorationTheme: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(
        iconColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
),
```

More about [inputDecorationTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/inputDecorationTheme.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, strangely enough my class doesn't contain iconColor parameter

Comment: Means you can't find `iconColor` on `inputDecorationTheme`?

Comment: Exactly, I tried to put this inside the class, but it only gives warning

Comment: Can you  recheck again, I am using flutter 2.10